# create new list with duplicates of list in list - python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I got a list of lists and don't know how to filter out duplicates (to a new list).

I tried extracting a path list and succesfully filtered out the duplicates,

```
dup_pathlist = pathA, pathA, pathC, pathC
```

but I couldn't recover the original connection between node and `dupl_pathlist` items. :(

I start with this:

```
node_path_list = [['node1', 'pathA'], ['node2', 'pathA'], ['node3', 'pathB'], ['node4', 'pathC'], ['node5', 'pathC']]
```

want to end here:

```
result = [['node1', 'pathA'], ['node2', 'pathA'],['node4', 'pathC'], ['node5', 'pathC']]
```

Comment: Does the order of the output matter?

Comment: Can there be more than one "path" that appears more than once?  If yes, should the resulting list contain all those paths?

Comment: Yes, there will appear more than one paths, and yes the list should contain every dupl.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
list1 = [ ['node1', 'pathA'], ['node2', 'pathA'], ['node3', 'pathB'], ['node4', 'pathC'], ['node5', 'pathA'] ]
result = [x for x in list1 if [y[1] for y in list1].count(x[1]) > 1]
```

EDIT: this should work better!

Comment: This does not yield the desired output!

Comment: @hymloth thanks for pointing that out! I reread the question and edited my response :)

Comment: @hymloth edited again for a nicer two-line solution to the non-problem :)

Comment: thanks a lot Andbdrew, this solved the (non) problem. (i am new to python).